# MySQL : Stored procedure returns null for last_insert_id

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a problem with SP in mySql when I want to select my identete it gives always null as value.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_details_facture(IN typefacture INT,
                IN codeactivite VARCHAR(255),
                IN qte INT, 
                IN pu DOUBLE, 
                IN unite VARCHAR(255), 
                IN montant DOUBLE)
BEGIN
DECLARE identete INT;
SELECT identete = numfacture FROM entetefacture WHERE numfacture = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
```

When I execute this it gives identite = numfacture as column's name and null as value.

```
CALL insert_details_facture(10,'l',10,12,'l',20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html).

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the **most recently executed INSERT statement**.

so result you are getting is obvious.

to get last record you can use limit.

```
SET identete = (SELECT numfacture FROM entetefacture ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not guaranteed to have a valid value. For instance, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) states:

> If the previous statement returned an error, the value of
> LAST_INSERT_ID() is undefined. For transactional tables, if the
> statement is rolled back due to an error, the value of
> LAST_INSERT_ID() is left undefined.

Similarly, if there have been no database changes for the current session, then the value will be undefined.

Also, if you want to set the value, then use `:=` in a `select`:

```
SELECT identete := numfacture
FROM entetefacture
WHERE numfacture = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Why not just get the last row in the table using `limit`?

```
SET identete = (SELECT numfacture FROM entetefacture ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);
```